# Can i use variables in Rails link_to method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Can i use variable for Rails link_to helper for making different link with variables?

For example,
`<%= link_to users, users_path %>` 
I have link like this,

And i'd like to change this url with variable `examples`

So i changed url like this,
`<%= link_to users, "#{examples}_path" %>` 
This not worked because of whole string change to url.

How can i change my link_to for use this with different variable for DRY codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking is really just how to perform dynamic method calls. In Ruby you can do it with `send` (and `public_send`):

```
<%= link_to users, send("#{examples}_path") %>
```

The difference between the two is that `send` will let you violate encapsulation and call private/protected methods.

You can also do it by calling `call` on the Method object:

```
<%= link_to users, method("#{examples}_path".to_sym).call %>
```

However you most likely don't even need this it in the first place. Just use the [polymorphic routing helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) to create links from models:

```
# a link to show whatever resource happens to be
<%= link_to resource.name, resource %>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_polymorphic_url(resource) %>
<%= link_to "New", new_polymorphic_url(resource_class) %>
<%= link_to "Frobnobize", polymorphic_url(resource, :frobnobize) %>

# a link to the index 
<%= link_to resource_class.model_name.plural, resource_class %>
```

These all use a set of heuristics to figure out what the corresponing path helper is and then call it dynamically with send.

Or if you want to link to a specific controller or action just use the functionality provided by [`url_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html):

```
# link to a specific controller action
<%= link_to "Baz", { controller: :foo, action: :bar } %>

# Will use the current controller 
<%= link_to "Baz", { action: :bar } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer with examples. It helped a lot.